# append a list with user input

Tags: python, list, input, append

I am tasked with adding a user input to the most recently selected number in a list. For example:

```
if choice == 1:
    table = int(input("Please select your table number(0-19): "))
    if tables[i] == "AVAILABLE":
        name = input("What is your name?: ")
        tables.append(name)
```

When i run this, the input is appended to the last table choice, and not the choice that the user has selected. For example, table choice is 5, user name is "Sam" - Sam shows in table 20 and not table 5.

Should I be using tables.insert? A little lost on this one. Thank you.

This is the code in its entirety thus far:

```
while True:
print("")
print("Welcome to Torrey's Restaurant")
print("=====Select Option to Continue=====")    
print("1- Reserve a Table")
print("2- Clear Reservation")
print("3- Status of Tables")
print("0- Exit")
choice = int(input("Choice? "))

count = 0
tables = []

for i in range(20):
    tables.append("AVAILABLE")     

if choice == 0:
    print("Thank you for using this program")
    break
    
if choice == 1:
    table = int(input("Please select your table number(0-19): "))
    if tables[i] == "AVAILABLE":
        name = input("What is your name?: ")
        tables.append(name)
    if not tables[i] == "AVAILABLE":
        print("The table you selected is unavailable")
```

tables{i} = the list of tables that can either be reserved, or are already reserved.

Comment: are you using Python?

Comment: yes i am using python, apologies.

Comment: what does tables[i] means ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `append()` use `inser()` to insert name into list.

```
if choice == 1:
    table = int(input("Please select your table number(0-19): "))
    if table in tables :
        name = input("What is your name?: ")
        tables.insert(table,name)
        print(tables)
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
Please select your table number(0-19): 1
What is your name?: Alex
[0, 'Alex', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Comment: thank you. This actually required if tables[i] in tables:

Comment: Ok. I just modified that part as i dont know how you have stored data in list. I think you need insert() part.

Comment: Yes. apologies for not including the stored data. insert worked. thank you